# Device in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, device

in Eclipse if i click on "window" - "show view" and then "other" there is no "device"
I mean the Option device is completly missing! There is no little mobilephonesymbol with the title "devices"

Can you please help me?

Comment: Same here (if you expect one, you are probably not using the right Eclipse distribution).

Comment: Is this Android or something that you want? This is not part of the standard Eclipse distribution. You have to either install the additional plug-ins or use the standalone distribution.

Comment: I bought a book for rookies in android appprogramming, this programm "eclipse" is on the cd, i installed it as it says in the book, but in one point i shall click on this option"devices" but that is the point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have not configured eclipse together with the android SDK appropriately.

I usually recommend beginners to
download Android ADT bundle from
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?utm_source=weibolife

It is a version of eclipse with everything pre configured.

Good luck!

Comment: Guys! You are awesome! Thx for your help! Now it works and i can continue! Only 10 Minutes waiting in this "forum" and there is my answere. Thx a lot. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install the [eclipse adt plugin](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

Or use the [eclipse adt bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html)

Then you have the views & perspectives for android development in your eclipse